# How to reduce page size with devexpress controls

Tags: optimization, size, devexpress, megabyte

I'm currently having an optimization problem with a page. This is a dashboard-like page, it contains and AspxNavBar (analogue of Accordion control) with 3 groups, groups contain 2 charts inside callback panel, 4 grids inside callback panel (1 main + 3 dependend), filtering controls with many comboboxes and a callback panel.

The total weight of the page is like ~4 megabytes, and, in addition, the first load of the page immediately starts a callback on dependent grids (first row is 'selected' in main grid) and on panel with charts (for chart resizing).

Is there a way to reduce page size, say, size of html or callback/view state for devexpress controls? I've searched and found advices to disable rows cache (that doesn't actually help), switch textboxes to native mode (i don't have textboxes), etc. I've also disabled viewstate for all grids and got rid of 2 callback panels, but that also didn't result in significant page size reduction ( ~ 1-2 %).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to reduce the page size from **4.5Mb** to **575Kb** using following:

---

1. I've disabled the ViewState from the whole page and all the inner user-controls. I've enabled it for individual controls where it was necessary (actually I've come up with no viewstate at all at the very end).
2. I've disabled callback state for some controls where it was possible, since i do not need any info about the page at callback except those that i explicitly pass as callback parameter.
3. I've simplified the layout a bit. (Got rid of another 2 callback panels on a filtering control - the was a panel with 2 comboboxes inside. I am now doing 2 callback on each combo-box instead of 1 panel-callback. Combo-box callbacks are faster and healthier since they don't return page layout as html). Also, I've changed labels to spans, buttons to inputs, etc. And i got rid of some nested  tags.
4. Used `RenderMode='Lightweight'` for `AspxNavBar` (actually, that only reduced page size by ~20kb)
5. Improved the code behind architecture, refactored javascript, reduced the number of callbacks and event postbacks (!filter is now applied using callback), etc.

---

That's all =) Hope that will help somebody.